# Exercise 8.5.19 Terence Tao's Analysis 1 (Initial segments)

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, set-theory, order-theory

The following extract is taken from Terence Tao's [Analysis 1 (Third Edition)](https://lms.umb.sk/pluginfile.php/111477/mod_page/content/5/TerenceTao_Analysis.I.Third.Edition.pdf)

> Exercise 8.5.19. Let $X$ be set, and let $\Omega$ be the space of all pairs $(Y,≤)$ where $Y$ is a subset of $X$ and $\leq$ is a well-ordering of $Y$. If $(Y,≤)$ and $(Y',≤')$ are elements of $\Omega$, **we say that $(Y,≤)$ is an *initial segment* of $(Y',≤')$ if there exists an $x \in Y'$ such that $Y = \{ y \in Y': y <' x\}$ (so in particular $Y \subsetneq Y'$), and for any $y, y' \in Y, y \le y'$ if and only if $y \le 'y'$** ...

The problem and the one I am currently struggling with is

> Let $(Y,≤)$ be an initial segment of $(Y',≤')$. For all $y,y' \in Y$, we have $y ≤ y'$ if and only if $y ≤' y'$.

What I have I tried is to use

> **Proposition 8.5.10** (Principle of strong induction). Let $X$ be a well-ordered set with an ordering relation $\le$, and let $P(n)$ be a property pertaining to an element $n\in X$ (i.e., for each $n \in X, P(n)$ is either a true statement or a false statement). Suppose that for every $n \in X$, we have the following implication: if $P(m)$ is true for all $m \in X$ with $m \lt \ n$, then $P(n)$ is also true. Prove that $P(n)$ is true for all $n \in X$.

to prove the above statement, and arguing by contradiction, but I am not making any progress. I would appreciate any help/hints that anyone can offer.

EDIT: I may have parsed the definition incorrectly. Am I correct in saying that the condition I am trying to prove is actually just part of the definition of an initial segment?

Comment: The definition of "initial segment" looked wrong to me - then I noticed the "...". If you left out part of the definition that was a bad idea...

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the text correctly then. I'll add the rest in as an edit

Comment: The part of the exercise I omitted I thought was not part of the definition. I have now added it

Comment: yes, that was the first reason i was confused; what you say you're asked to prove is in fact just part of the definition. Possibly you're still not telling us everything or something

Comment: Answer to your edit: yes.

Comment: I downloaded the pdf to try to figure out what you were omitting. I can't find the exercise...

Comment: In any case, something hugely important that you should remember in the future: You were stuck. All I did was suggest you should not ignore half of the definition and that solved your problem! (in case my point is not clear: trying to learn math without paying *careful* attention to the definitions is absurd)

Comment: Agreed. I would have saved myself a few hours if I had read more carefully. Thank you for helping me @David C. Ullrich

Comment: @WilliamElliot: If that was not the intended use of a block quote, I don't know what is the intended use.